# Using Avalonia Command Parameters to reference an instance of a class

Tags: avalonia, commandparameter

I am trying to use an avalonia button to call a function that requires an argument with the type of my class "Flashcard". Here's the relevent code,

```xml
<SampleControl xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<Button.CommandParameter>
    <sys:Flashcard>$self</sys:Flashcard>
</Button.CommandParameter>`
```

I've tried messing around with the sys:flashcard bit for a while but with only errors cropping up.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to pass a parameter in a command is to use Bindings. Basically, you have a view - .axaml markup file with code-behind c# class. In this view you can define binding context, either in markup or in code - you can look it up [here](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/concepts/the-mvvm-pattern/avalonia-ui-and-mvvm).

After setting up a binding context to your view model you can create a property with a type you need - in your case it would look like this:

```cs
public Flashcard MyFlashcard { get; set; }
```

And as a final step, you need to bind this property as a command parameter in a markup. You also can create a command and bind it a similar way.

```xml
<Button Command={Binding MyCommand} CommandParameter={Binding MyFlashcard}>
```

As for creating a command, you can read more [here](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/tutorials/music-store-app/button-command#reactive-command).

Hope it helps!

EDIT: In case if you need to bind a visual element as a command parameter, explore [this docs section](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/basics/data/data-binding/data-binding-syntax).